# Resharper cli does not format indents

Tags: c#, resharper

I want to clean up my code by using jb cleanupcode --settings="MY.sln.DotSettings" SLN_NAME
In my dotsettings I have rules like (test values)
`<s:Int64 x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INDENT_SIZE/@EntryValue">1</s:Int64> <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INDENT_STYLE/@EntryValue">Tab</s:String> <s:Int64 x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/TAB_WIDTH/@EntryValue">8</s:Int64>`
But it anyway format with 4 spaces. How to make that this command change indents as well?

I have tried many options like --settings, --disable-settings-layers etc.

Comment: How did you check that it indents with 4 spaces?

Comment: In particular: did you make sure that you didn't look at it with an editor that indents a tab as 4 spaces? Use a Hex Editor instead.